# Overlaying colors in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I have tried to make a parametric plot with transparent regions, but the color is different in the region where the plot overlaps itself. How can I make it the same color in the entire plot?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include copy and paste-able code for a **minimal working example** that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can copy code directly from the input cell of the notebook and paste it in the Edit window where there is a `{  }` icon to format it as such. Forum participants can assist you further only if they can experiment with your code in their own notebook environments. Thanks.